# What collection should I choose?

Tags: java

I need just a collection of two pairs of data, none of them is going to be null. I don't need any sorting or other possibilities. What implementation of `Map` should I choose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Map Implementations](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/map.html):

> The three general-purpose Map
>   implementations are HashMap, TreeMap
>   and LinkedHashMap. If you need
>   SortedMap operations or key-ordered
>   Collection-view iteration, use
>   TreeMap; **if you want maximum speed and
>   don't care about iteration order, use
>   HashMap**; if you want near-HashMap
>   performance and insertion-order
>   iteration, use LinkedHashMap. In this
>   respect, the situation for Map is
>   analogous to Set. Likewise, everything
>   else in the Set Implementations
>   section also applies to Map
>   implementations

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` is usually the default choice. It gives one O(1) lookup.

Comment: Sort of: in terms of the lookup itself, it is O(1). However, the key may not hash in constant time. E.g. string hashing is O(n) where n is the size of the string.

Comment: @John Gaughan well, yes, but the key hashing doesn't depend on the size of the collection. :)

Answer (score 1):

HashMap is most commonly used for such Key-Value pairs.